# Getting started with JMH: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, benchmarking

My first JMH benchmark code:

```
package org.sample;

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;

public class MyBenchmark {

    @Benchmark
    public void testMethod() {
        // This is a demo/sample template for building your JMH benchmarks. Edit as needed.
        // Put your benchmark code here.
        int i = 100;
        while (i > 0) {
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

Running it with *any* of the following commands results in

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

on the very first warmup iteration.

```
java -jar target/benchmarks.jar
java -Xmx256m -jar target/benchmarks.jar
java -Xmx500m -jar target/benchmarks.jar
java -Xmx700m -jar target/benchmarks.jar
java -Xms512m -Xmx1152m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -jar target/benchmarks.jar
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the code I *did* have was memory intensive (adding a string to itself a hundred times), and I did not rebuild the project before running it again.

Once rebuilt with

```
mvn clean install
```

it works fine with the default command/heap size:

```
java -jar target/benchmarks.jar
```